# Standard module version numbers

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, version

Is there any convention for version numbers and community modules?

I see a varied combination of the following as starting numbers:

```
1.0.0
0.1.0
0.0.1
```

I always tend to use the last one: 0.0.1 but asking if there is a standard we should all try and follow?

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard as far as I know for Magento specifically. However, the three number setup is commonly setup as major.minor.patch, although I'm sure there are several variations of that. Please see the following articles that offer various insights into the different types of version methods.

http://semver.org/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826580/what-rules-does-software-version-numbering-follow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377655/code-version-change-rules/3377717#3377717